# Can't access the Webservice in the Kendo ui Mobile App

Tags: java, android, web-services, kendo-ui

Can somebody help me dude. I am trying create a simple mobile application for my Company. As it has to be a platform independent app I decided to use the New Kendo ui With phone gap.

Everything seem to be working fine But I am unable to access webservice of any kind into the mobile emulator. I am using android emulator on windows 7 PC. I have given the internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file as well. Here is my Kendoui accessing the service

```
TaskManager.DataAccess = {}

TaskManager.DataAccess._sprints = null;

TaskManager.DataAccess.getSprints = function(callback) {
  try {

    if (TaskManager.DataAccess._sprints == null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/TaskManager.Mvc/Mobile/Sprints",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "d",
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            alert("helloo");
            TaskManager.DataAccess._sprints = response.sprints;
            callback(TaskManager.DataAccess._sprints);
        })
    }
  } catch (err) {
  }
}
```

I tried compiling the getting started example on telerik website here is the link http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-22/building_your_first_kendo_ui_mobile_phonegap_application.aspx.

I am able to get the webservice working if i access it through any browser on pc but somehow the data is not accessible into the emulator. I dont know the reason but its driving me crazy.

I tried this example as well http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page:kendo-ui-mobile-task-manager-part-1 but same result.

Any kind of help is appreciated. please

Answer (score 0):

Change your url to:

```
url: "http://10.0.2.2/TaskManager.Mvc/Mobile/Sprints",
```

Refer to [Common Tasks and How to Do Them in Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias)

> If you need to refer to your host computer's localhost, such as when you want the emulator client to contact a server running on the same host, use the alias 10.0.2.2 to refer to the host computer's loopback interface. From the emulator's perspective, localhost (127.0.0.1) refers to its own loopback interface.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh For the Speedy Reply. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately no luck. Do I need any special permission for Phone Gap
application to access the internet resource?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to specify `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. If it still doesn't wrk, try to access the link from the browser on the emulator

Comment: yes I tried to acces the link through Emulator browser and it working fine I have the internet permission in Android XMl file

Comment: I am not getting any error. its just that the Data is not accessible into the emulator. After changing the URL as you suggest before the loading sign dissappear after 1 sec or so. Before it just keeps on loading.

Comment: Make sure the parameters for that you specified for the ajax function call is right. If possible, try the simplest piece of code and isolate the problem.

Comment: Made some progress now My call to the service from emulator is reaching the service and i am able to get the response. But still it did not display anything on screen. After putting alert insid ethe call function with response as parameter. I came to knoe that it four objects inside it.